# Adding shadow around MapView marker

Tags: react-native, google-maps-markers, shadow, react-native-maps

Is it possible to add a shadow around a react native MapView Marker? I've been trying to add the shadow in all ways possible, but it seems the marker just ignores it. All I want is for my marker to be 'elevated' a bit so it's not directly on the map. Is there any way to achieve this?